# Syntax error in InsertCommand from OleDbCommandBuilder

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to add a new order into my database using this code. I have used the same code before however its not working now. Can you please help?

I am using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 express edition and Microsoft Access.

I have four tables.

```
    CurrentRowNo = 0
    ' Purpose: Add new Account record and assign its default values
    ' Clear the Account table in the DataSet ready for a new record to be added
    SandRDataSet.Tables("Stock").Clear()
    'Add a new record to the studnet table
    Dim driveletter As String = Application.StartupPath.Substring(0, 1)
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & driveletter & ":\raheem\Computing\Database\SandR.accdb")
    cn.Open()
    Dim daStock As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Stock;", cn)
    Dim sqlcmdbldStudent As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daStock)
    'Fill the database
    daStock.Fill(SandRDataSet, "Stock")

    Dim test As DataRow = SandRDataSet.Tables("Stock").NewRow

    test("Product/Service number") = txtProductNo.Text
    test("Product/ Service name") = txtProductName.Text
    test("minimum level") = txtMin.Text
    test("maximum level") = txtMax.Text
    test("Quantity") = txtQuantity.Text
    test("Price") = txtPrice.Text


    SandRDataSet.Tables("Stock").Rows.Add(test)

    sqlcmdbldStudent.GetInsertCommand()

    daStock.InsertCommand = sqlcmdbldStudent.GetInsertCommand

    daStock.Update(SandRDataSet.Stock)
    DisplayAccount()

    cn.Dispose()
    cn.Close()
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have that column names in your table (Space and forward slashes) then I suggest you to set the [QuotePrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.quoteprefix(v=vs.110).aspx) and QuoteSuffix to your OleDbCommandBuilder

```
Dim sqlcmdbldStudent As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daStock)
sqlcmdbldStudent.QuotePrefix = "["
sqlcmdbldStudent.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

This will force the fields names created by the command builder to be enclosed in square brackets and correctly interpreted by the database engine

Comment: do i have to remove this section                                Dim test As DataRow = SandRDataSet.Tables("Stock").NewRow

    test("Product/Service number") = txtProductNo.Text
    test("Product/ Service name") = txtProductName.Text
    test("minimum level") = txtMin.Text
    test("maximum level") = txtMax.Text
    test("Quantity") = txtQuantity.Text
    test("Price") = txtPrice.Text

Comment: No, you just add the two properties to your OleDbCommandBuilder. So when you call GetInsertCommand you receive a commandtext where all the fields name are correctly enclosed in square brakets